# Gtk Notebook size dynamically change

Tags: python, gtk

I have a notebook window. I want to change dynamically size. I did expand dynamically, but I couldn't shrink it. I used `win.set_size_request(w,h)` for expand. How can I shrink dynamically?

Comment: How are you sizing it? With a button click? or something else?

Answer (score 0):

You can't force a `GtkNotebook` to shrink by using it's API. There are other ways of doing it. If the widget inside the Notebook shrinks, then the Notebook will shrink, although you might need to take into account the widgets in other pages, and I'm not sure this works. You could wrap your GtkNotebook in a custom container that force the shrink on the notebook.

And ... I can't think of any more ways of doing it.
[gtk_widget_set_size_request](http://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkWidget.html#gtk-widget-set-size-request) will set only the minimum size of the widget, overriding its natural size.

Answer (score 0):

You likely have widgets on your pages that are stopping them from shrinking. You may need to put the content of your pages in a ViewPort or ScrolledWindow to get the effect you are looking.